# Adding custom parameter in an url on Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
connection = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.wdyl.com/profanity?q=" + text_to_check)
```

I don't know why but the code above is not working in python 3.5 and after several hours of searching i yet to find any answer for that. What i want to do is adding text_to_check string in the end of url

The error i'm receiving is:

```
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

Comment: "is not working" is about the most useless definition of a problem. Please explain what you get exactly.

Comment: i edited my question. If i remove + text_to_check part, the url alone is working without any error or issue

Comment: What is your `text_to_check` when it fails?

Comment: it's full of text from a .txt file. I can print it there is no issue there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `text_to_check`.

Try this:

```
query = urllib.parse.urlencode({'q': text_to_check})
urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.wdyl.com/profanity?" + query)
```

and `print` the `query` variable to see what has to happen with your "full of text from a .txt file" in order to work correctly as a URL.

Comment: it worked thank you! but i did not understand the code. I searched a lot but none of the solutions provided is similar to this approach

Comment: @fuzunspm - you can also have a look at `requests`, which may shorten the number of methods you will need: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls